# EAGLE Footprint with only top pad and a hole through it

Tags: eaglecad, footprint

I need top create a footprint with only one top layer pad (no bottom pad).

To create a through hole pad and remove the solder mask on the bottom side will not work, because the hole needs to be none-plated.

With Eagle 9.6.2 I tried with polygons but I can't control the isolation gap around the polygon or the hole.

Any ideas?

Comment: are you referring to a SMT pad ?

Comment: Please show a picture or screenshot of the pad you created using a polygon.

Answer (score 1):

Just use an SMT pad on the top (roundness set to 100%), and a drill hole in the centre. Because there is then no pad on the bottom side the hole will end up basically a non-PTH.

Eagle will give a DRC error due to the drill being in the pad, but you can safely ignore the error as it is intentional.

I use the same approach for solder standoffs whereby a large pad is needed on one side, and an unplated hole in the middle. Had no issue with PCB fabs understanding what I needed.